# How to clear an image from a javafx label

Tags: javafx, label

I would like to clear a javafx label which could have text or picture in it. I know how to clear the text, but not sure how to remove the image, help please

To clear the text of the label I am using the following

```
facebook_Label.setText("");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the Graphic of the Label to `null`

```
facebook_Label.setGraphic(null);
```